# Retrieve XMl Data Using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am very new to Java and Xml parsing. My requirement is to take a xml file and store the XML file's data in a database in the table and columns format using java. I tried in google to get the right solution for it. But I am helpless. Till now what I did is, I can get the xml data dynamically and store either tag names or values. But my req is to take tag names only once as column names   and data related to particular column in the row format can anyone please correct my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Java Code

```
 import java.io.*;
    import javax.xml.parsers.*;
    import org.w3c.dom.*;
    import org.xml.sax.*;

    public class XmlData{
     static public void main(String[] arg){
     try {
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     System.out.print("Enter XML File Path: ");
     String xmlFile = bf.readLine();
     //Store the String into the File
     File file = new File(xmlFile);
     if(file.exists()){
     // Create a factory
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     // Use the factory to create a builder
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
     Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
     System.out.println("Root element of the document: "+ docEle.getNodeName());
     // Get a list of all elements in the document
     NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

     int totalElements = list.getLength();

     System.out.println("XML Elements: " + totalElements);
     for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) 
     {
     // Get element
     Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
     String tag=element.getTagName();
     String name=list.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
     System.out.println(name);
     System.out.print(tag);
     System.out.print(" ");
     //System.out.println(element.getNodeName());


     }
     }
     else{
     System.out.print("File not found!");
     }
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
     System.exit(1);
     }
     }
    }
```

Output for this code:

```
company 
staff 
firstname 
lastname 
nickname 
salary 
staff 
firstname 
lastname 
nickname 
salary
```

Expected Output:

```
FirstName, Lastname, nickname  , salary  //column

yong     ,mook kim, mkyong     , 100000   // rows
low      ,yin fong, fong fong   ,200000
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you have already created a database table with four columns - FirstNAme, LastName, NickName, Salary.

It's really straight forward to read data and store in DB.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ParseStaff {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        parseFile();
    }
    public static void parseFile() {
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            //Document dom = db.parse("employees.xml");
            Document dom = db.parse("C:\\GAE\\NetBeansProjects\\Test\\src\\statff.xml");
            //get the root element
            Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
            //get a nodelist of elements
            NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("staff");

            if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    //get the employee element
                    Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    String firstname = getTextValue(el, "firstname");
                    String lastname = getTextValue(el, "lastname");
                    String nickname = getTextValue(el, "nickname");
                    int salary = getIntValue(el, "salary");

                    System.out.println(firstname);
                    System.out.println(lastname);
                    System.out.println(nickname);
                    System.out.println(salary);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private static String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
        String textVal = null;
        NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            Element el = (Element) nl.item(0);
            textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        return textVal;
    }
    private static int getIntValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
        return Integer.parseInt(getTextValue(ele, tagName));
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
yong
mook kim
mkyong
100000
low
yin fong
fong fong
200000
```

Comment: +1 @sreehari: indeed the getTextValue helper method is crucial! But I shouldn't say it's really straight-forward because of the complexity needed to achieve this very common need XD

Comment: hi this is not what i want, by dynamic i need to create column names and instead of one after another i want in column and row format

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how this XML is huge. But if xml is big you can't import all XML into memory.

For this reason, you can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) library.

DSM allows you to process XML as a stream and partially process data.

first of all, you must define yaml mapping file as follows.

```
result:
  type: object     # result is map
  path: /.+staff  # path is regex. its match with /company/staff
  function: processStuff  # call processStuff function when /company/stuff tag is closed
  fields:
    firstName:  # firstName is not same as firstname (camel case)
      path: firstname
    lastName:
      path: lastname
    nickName:
      path: nickname
    salary: long
```

Create FunctionExecutor for process staff.

```
FunctionExecutor processStuff=new FunctionExecutor(){

            @Override
            public void execute(Params params) {

                // directly serialize Stuff class
                //Stuff stuff=params.getCurrentNode().toObject(Stuff.class);

                Map<String,Object> stuff= (Map<String,Object>)params.getCurrentNode().toObject();
                System.out.println(stuff);
                // process stuff ; save to db. call service etc.
            }
        };
```

Use DSM to process xml

```
     DSMBuilder builder = new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML);

       // register processStuff Function
        builder.registerFunction("processStuff",processStuff);

        DSM dsm= builder.create();
        Object object =  dsm.toObject(xmlContent);
```

Output:

```
{firstName=yong, lastName=mook kim, nickName=mkyong, salary=100000}
{firstName=low, lastName=yin fong, nickName=fong fong, salary=200000}
```